# Bootstrap 4 card-columns of same height

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to build a website with the new bootstrap 4.0, and trying to use new card function.

What I try to get is what you see in puicture A.

[image]

After reducing columns at 2,

```
.card-columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 0;
}
```

And putting everything inside card-columns div,

```
<div class="card-columns">
 <div class="card">card1</div>
 <div class="card">card2</div>
 <div class="card">card3</div>
 <div class="card">card4</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">landscapeImage</div>
```

I obtain the result in B, with a white space between the shortest column and the landscape image,

and I would like to force the 2 columns to be the same height.

I was thinking to putting everythin in a big div with the height of the shortest column, and overflowing the highest column, but I can't do it...

What can I do?
Is it possible to do it in a clean way?

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: please try to add class `h-100` in your green column(which is available space.).

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="card h-100 card-body">
```

here is an example [bootstrap-4-equal-height-cards](https://www.codeply.com/go/jbcgzs2Nzq/bootstrap-4-equal-height-cards)

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you (+1). Don't understand the downgrade.